# Adding a formula to current cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I got a seemingly simple question that I cannot find an answer for, most likely due to my limited Excel vocabulary... Any help would be much appreciated!

I update our company's catalog on a frequent basis, and this involves updating the prices of thousands of products. We keep an Excel version of the price lists for our clients, and these files need to stay up to date as well. All the company files have simple currency values in them, and I'd like to be able to update them all with a cell that contains a percentage multiplier. To better illustrate my needs, here's an example:

```
   Col A   Col B
1 $5      105% (multiplier)
2 $10
3 $15
```

I'm looking for a way to quickly and uniformly insert part of a formula `"=$B$1*"` into any selected range of cells `A1:A3` (which already have values in them) so that their formula line would individually appear as `"=$B$1*cell.value*"` and produce an updated price, as opposed to `"=$B$1*cell.reference".`

Ultimately though, I am seeking a method that would allow me to simply change the multiplier cell and the associated range of existing prices would adjust automatically. But I want to do so without deleting or retyping the existing column of prices. If there are smarter ways to do this, please advise.

PS** I know I can Paste Special and modify a selected range of cells (multiply by the value of another cell), but I feel like the multiplier scenario would be even faster since most product categories increase a certain percentage every time there is a change.

Comment: why not make a helper column that has `=$B$1*A1` then drag it down and hide column A?

Comment: Why not in Column c put the formula `=A1*$B$1`.  Your way if the prices themselves change you will need to rerun any code to fix all the formulas.  This way you can change both the multiplier and the wholesale price.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
Sub CellFormula()
Dim Cell As Variant
For Each Cell In Selection
  Cell.Formula = "=$B$1*" & Cell.Value
Next
End Sub
```

this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the find and replace, which will look in formulas.  Once it's set up, you can replace all.  There is also a feature to use regex expressions in this dialog.